# to many files when starting new jhipster project

Tags: startup, jhipster

i follow the tutorial from matt on:
http://jhipster.github.io/video-tutorial/

when i do cloc . i see i have much and much more files i would expect:

```
$ cloc .
66717 text files.
20401 unique files.                                          
24466 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=128.46 s (115.7 files/s, 15523.0 lines/s)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank            comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Javascript                    13322         222956         357190            1266221
HTML                            676           6984           1047          44885
CSS                              76           1883            932          22029
Java                            262           3548           1854          15641
XML                              53           3383           1395          11307
LESS                             79           1388           1546           7269
C/C++ Header                     18           1032            300           5109
YAML                            190            221            346           3466
CoffeeScript                     47            783            699           2467
make                             58            417            523           1271
Bourne Shell                     31            234            202           1097
Maven                             1             12             34            824
Perl                              2             87            170            584
DTD                               1            179            177            514
SASS                              5             42             25            273
C++                               4             43             26            260
IDL                               6             38              0            167
Bourne Again Shell                3             28             36            140
D                                 6              0              0            118
Scala                             1             16              7            118
JavaServer Faces                  3              3              0            109
Smarty                            6             17             30             91
DOS Batch                         1             24              2             64
Python                            1              7              7             36
XSLT                              1              5              0             32
C#                                2              3              1             27
ASP.Net                           2              5              0             23
C                                 1              7              4             23
OCaml                             1              5             15              6
Lisp                              1              0              0              6
PowerShell                        1              2              2              4
Lua                               1              0                  0              2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          14862         243352         366570        1384183
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

why is that?
in total it is 610 mb large!

it seems there are a lot of node modules:

```
$ du -h -d1
584M    ./node_modules
24K ./gulp
26M ./src
64K ./.mvn
610M    .
```

is this correct?
and what do i need to add to source control?

thanks

Comment: In the mean time i watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2776&v=kkHN2G_nXV0 and here matt explains about the node_modules. and i noticed matt did cloc before node modules were installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. Most of those files are NPM dependencies, as you mentioned.

The generated `.gitignore` should already be configured properly and will ignore node_modules.